# str_replace backwards from end of string?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm using str_replace to replace the string '000' with ',000':

```
 str_replace('000', ',000', $MYVAR)
```

So 1000 becomes 1,000. The problem is that 10000 becomes 1,0000 but I want it to become 10,000. How can I make str_replace parse from the right to the left, rather than the default left to right?

In an additional I need to remove any occurrences of '.00'. so '1.00' should become '1'. 10000.00 should become '10,000'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it that way, use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format), which'll handle it all for you.

Comment: Example: `echo number_format($MYVAR, 0, '', ',');`, or, money format: `echo number_format($MYVAR, 2, ',', '.');`